# How to migrate flutter_web to flutter in hummingbird?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, hummingbird

In the latest [flutter version(1.9)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzNd3yyLcaU) they give the option to migrate flutter_web package to flutter master package. So how to create a single flutter project for both mobile and web?. How to convert existing flutter web project from flutter_web to flutter?.

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Answer (score 0):

What I did, and work well, is create a new project from scratch, enabled web with 'flutter config --enable-web', and copied the lib content on it, just needed to update the pubspec.yaml, be aware that now the assets are declared in the yaml, like a normal flutter app, I hope it It helps.

To start your Flutter web in chrome: flutter run -d chrome

To build: flutter build web